why is this animation texture baker shader not compiling?
ok so I'm trying to bake an animation into a texture so I can use that in a material to run later. I currently trying to use the following code I found on GitHub to do the job for me:
the_code
I don't know much about unity shaders to be honest, but I'm familiar with them generally from using webgl.
the shader works as expected and I can use the animation on a material to display the animation. however when it comes to compiling this code, it fails. annoyingly the code has errors and runs as expected. this doesn't allow me to build my game due to the errors. the error I'm getting is "syntax error: unexpected token 'cbuffer'." seemingly cbuffers can't be used inside unity_instance_buffers because the first is a constant and shared and the second is per instance. I'm unsure of what to do here; hopefully someone can offer some assistance.
and in case you're wondering why I'm trying to bake an animation inside a texture, it's because I'm trying to run the same animation on massive amounts of characters/gameobjects without experiencing lag and I've found this does the trick (again, creating a build later on is where I run into issues). if anyone has alternative suggestions for that I'd appreciate that too, but the one mentioned first seems to be the faster solution).
thanks

I tried removing the cbuffer, but that caused the animation to unsuccessfully bake into the texture and instead static data seemed to be baked into the texture.

I tried moving the cbuffer outside the unity_instance_buffer, but I'm unsure which properties to include in which buffer.



are you using the same unity version?

Are you saying that the code on the master branch of that TextureBaker repository has a syntax error? If you have a simple example to demonstrate the syntax error, please edit the question to include a code excerpt.
